# Add border/background color/color text of embedded pop-up

Tags: custom-background

I have been trying in vain to give color to my subscription pop-up. I believe it must be something quite easy and straight-forward but, since I do not understand a thing about html, I really need your help. Below follows the code.

PS: I would like to have a strong border line in red, all the pop-up itself in black and the text in white.

#mc_embed_signup{background:#fff; clear:left; font:14px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; }

### Text title

Text 1.
Text 2.

**Name** 

**Email Address ***

(function($) {window.fnames = new Array(); window.ftypes = new Array();fnames[1]='FNAME';ftypes[1]='text';fnames[0]='EMAIL';ftypes[0]='email';fnames[2]='LNAME';ftypes[2]='text';fnames[3]='ADDRESS';ftypes[3]='address';fnames[4]='PHONE';ftypes[4]='phone';fnames[5]='BIRTHDAY';ftypes[5]='birthday';fnames[6]='MMERGE6';ftypes[6]='imageurl';}(jQuery));var $mcj = jQuery.noConflict(true);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Simple CSS Styling

Add this to your [CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_intro.asp)

```
 #mc_embed_signup {
    background:#000;
    color:fff;
    border:1px solid red;
    padding:20px;
    }
```

### Adjust to Your Preferences

You can adjust the border width by giving it a larger than 1px value, such as this:

`border:8px solid red;`

These are the [colour values](https://htmlcolorcodes.com/color-picker/) used. They are called Hexadecimals (Hex):

> `#fff` = White
>
> `#000` = Black

Comment: That is great, thanks a lot. And do you know how I make the margins bigger? Right now, for instance, the text, the "Name", "Email address" and subscribe button are touching the edge of the border.

Comment: Your welcome Andreas :) You can use padding or margin. Padding is often the better option. For example: `#mc_embed_signup {background:#000; color:fff; border:1px solid red; padding:20px;}` If this answers your question, please concider upvoting and makeing as the correct answer via the tick.

Comment: I've added `padding` to the answer I provided :)

Comment: Perfect! Just a last question (promise): How do I give color to the subscribe button? I have tried this but it is not working...<div class="clear"><b><font color="white"><input id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button" name="subscribe" type="submit" value="Subscribe" /></b></font></div>

Comment: `#mc-embedded-subscribe button {background:blue; color:#fff;}`

Comment: Or with a hex blue: `#mc-embedded-subscribe button {background:#425ff4; color:#fff;}`